# ASP.NET requestValidationMode whitelist?

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation

I am using the `requestValidationMode="4.5"` in my web.config to prevent XSS. However, I added a small wysiwyg editor to the page and I would like to enable few harmless html tags to pass through the validation.

Is there any way to use some kind of whitelist in this case? I can't find any way to customize the validation and I don't want to disable it or downgrade to 2.0

Comment: You can disable the request validation mode for that specific page.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to get rid of the rest of the validation benefits.